# How can I open MDN link in coc.css popup?

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, plugin-coc, snippets

Sorry for my English. I installed coc-nvim plugin in my vim (gvim in windows) after that I insert `CocInstall coc-css`  command for css snippets.

[image]

In this picture I highlighted MDN Reference.
How can I open MDN Reference link by keyboard. Is that a link? I want to open that with a shortcut key .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code map `L` to an action that open the online documentation if any:

```
let g:browser = '~/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

function! OpenDocumentationUrl() abort
  try
    let url = matchstr(CocAction('getHover')[0], 'https\?://[^ )]*')
  catch
    return
  endtry
  if url != ''
    let cmd = 'silent !"' .. expand(g:browser) .. '" ' .. url
    execute cmd
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <S-l> :call OpenDocumentationUrl()<CR>
```

It doesn't work on the menu but on the selected keyword (a bit like `K` shows the documentation in a popup)

Comment: Thanks , I change the path for Firefox and It works for me. It is great idea. But  which plugin do you use for snippets in vim personally ?

Comment: I don't use snippet much but the two I use are [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) which is very powerful for programming language and [emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) which is very common for html programming :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If the solution solves your problem could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons, it allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: Can we have snippets without installing any plugin? Do we have a repository for this? just add them to the vimrc file!

Comment: Snippets are insert mapping that trigger insert depending of the context. You can write simple vimscript that does that. But you'll reinvent the wheel and you Snippet will not be discovered by coc.

Comment: I mean just using abbreviation. e.g : `iabbrev colo console.log(); `. There is no need to install any plugin by this way.

Comment: Indeed but they will not be discovered and suggested by coc.